# Using XDocument to write raw XML

Tags: c#, xml, excel, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in XML Spreadsheet 2003 format (so Excel can read it).  I'm writing out the document using the XDocument class, and I need to get a newline in the body of one of the `<Cell>` tags.  Excel, when it reads and writes, requires the files to have the literal string `&#10;` embedded in the string to correctly show the newline in the spreadsheet.  It also writes it out as such.

The problem is that XDocument is writing CR-LF (\r\n) when I have newlines in my data, and it automatically escapes ampersands for me when I try to do a `.Replace()` on the input string, so I end up with `&amp;#10;` in my file, which Excel just happily writes out as a string literal.

Is there any way to make XDocument write out the literal `&#10;` as part of the XML stream?  I know I can do it by deriving from XmlTextWriter, or literally just writing out the file with a TextWriter, but I'd prefer not to if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if it might be better to use `XmlWriter` directly, and `WriteRaw`?

A  quick check shows that `XmlDocument` makes a slightly better job of it, but xml and whitespace gets tricky very quickly...

Comment: Agreed, though I suggest XmlWriter.WriteWhitespace(), not WriteRaw, to output specific characters for whitespace.

Comment: Looking like I'm going to have to go that way.

Answer (score 2):

I battled with this problem for a couple of days and finally came up with this solution. I used `XMLDocument.Save(Stream)` method, then got the formatted XML string from the stream. Then I replaced the `&amp;#10;` occurrences with `&#10;` and used the TextWriter to write the string to a file.

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><?mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet'?><Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">";
xml += "<Styles><Style ss:ID=\"s1\"><Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Center\" ss:WrapText=\"1\"/></Style></Styles>";
xml += "<Worksheet ss:Name=\"Default\"><Table><Column ss:Index=\"1\" ss:AutoFitWidth=\"0\" ss:Width=\"75\" /><Row><Cell ss:StyleID=\"s1\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Hello&amp;&#35;10;&amp;&#35;10;World</Data></Cell></Row></Table></Worksheet></Workbook>";

System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); //load the xml string
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
doc.Save(stream); //save the xml as a formatted string
stream.Position = 0; //reset the stream position since it will be at the end from the Save method
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
string formattedXML = reader.ReadToEnd(); //fetch the formatted XML into a string
formattedXML = formattedXML.Replace("&amp;#10;", "&#10;"); //Replace the unhelpful &amp;#10;'s with the wanted endline entity
System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\test1.xls");
writer.Write(formattedXML); //write the XML to a file
writer.Close();
```